# Type "MyClass" does not conform to protocol "Collection_Delegate"

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a class **MyClass** implementing a generic function of a delegate **Collection_Delegate**.

My classes **Collection** and **Item** are superclasses for some specific classes

```
protocol Collection_Delegate {
        func onFetchAllCompleted<T, U where T: Collection<U>, U: Item>(collection: T, error: String?)
}

class Collection<T>: Item {

    private var items: [T]

    override init (communicator: CG_API_Communicator) {
        items = [T]()
        super.init(communicator: communicator)
    }

    internal func fetchAll() {
        fatalError(notImplemented)
    }

    internal func onFetchAllCompleted(error: String?, json: JSON?) {
        fatalError(notImplemented)
    }

    internal func appendItem(item: T) {
        self.items.append(item)
    }

    internal func getItems() -> [T] {
        return self.items
    }
}

class Item {

    var itemDataRaw: JSON?        

    func toString() -> String? {
        var retval: String?
        if let value: String = itemDataRaw?.rawString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            retval = value
        } else {
            retval = "Something went badly wrong"
        }
        return retval
    }
 }
```

Now in some subclasses of **Collection** I want to call the generic onFetAllCompleted function of the delegate avery subclass has. But the class implementing the **Collection_Delegate** protocol causing compiler errors

```
class MyClass: Collection_Delegate { // Error

    func onFetchAllCompleted<T, U where T: Collection<U>, U: Item>(collection: T, error: String?){
        println("MyClass.onFetchAllCompleted:\(_stdlib_getTypeName(collection))") // This displays the right class name of the subclasses
        let item: Item = collection.getItems()[0] //Error
        let string = item.toString()
    }
}
```

Here we go. The class **MyClass* gets the error

> Type "MyClass" does not conform to protocol "Collection_Delegate"

Within the generic function I get the error

> 'U' is not convertible to 'Item'

So what am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the generic stuff work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you over complicated things a bit with your generic function declaration. If I understood you correctly your onFetchAllCompleted function takes parameter T which is Collection of U's and U is an Item. If that is correct the above expression can be simplified like this :  onFetchAllCompleted function takes parameter T which is Collection of Items. So your protocol and class should look like this

```
protocol Collection_Delegate {
    func onFetchAllCompleted<T: Collection<Item>>(collection: T, error: String?)
}

class MyClass: Collection_Delegate {

    func onFetchAllCompleted<T: Collection<Item>>(collection: T, error: String?){
        println("MyClass.onFetchAllCompleted:\(_stdlib_getTypeName(collection))") // This displays the right class name of the subclasses
        let item: Item = collection.getItems()[0] //Error
        let string = item.toString()
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helped you

Comment: Well, thanks, this helped me getting the stuff to work.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there isn't any need for the `T` either; you could just have  `func onFetchAllCompleted(collection: Collection<Item>, error: String?)`

Comment: Looks like I missed that too. You are absolutely right

Comment: Actually I made it "onFetchAllCompleted<T: Item>(collection: Collection<T>, error: String?)" to fit to the rest of the structure, but it kind of does the same

Comment: The question still is... why Does the class not confirm the protocol. It may be complicated, but it fits the method stub of the function and there are no syntax errors...

Comment: I think the problem was with incorrect usage of where clause. From the "The Swift Programing Language" > A where clause enables you to require that an associated type conforms to a certain protocol, and/or that certain type parameters and associated types be the same , and in your case where didn't require any of them